# Responsive Rollover Images in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

Ok, so I have a grid of images in a page.  I put them in as single images, linked each to the URL of another page, gave each image div its own class, and then added CSS styling for each class for the rollover.  This code works in Chrome and Safari:

```
.advertising a:hover {
content: url('image1');
z-index: 1;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
height: auto;
opacity: 1;
}
```

It does not work in Firefox, however (no rollover at all).  This somewhat works in Firefox:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
.advertising a:hover:before{
content: url('image2');
width: 100%;
position: relative;
height: auto;
opacity: 1;
 z-index: 1;
}}
```

It works in that the rollover happens, but the new image is not responsive and displays above the original image instead of on top of it.

Help?  I'm a CSS newbie trying to figure this out on my own, so any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Please show us the html code and make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) (not working for anonymous users) or a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/pen/). BTW, if you put a different class to each div, why don't you use `background-image` instead of `content` or a img element?

Comment: I've tried doing this a few ways. I'm using Wordpress and a theme which has a visual composer that allows for easy creation of columns, divs, and individual image widgets.  You can also add extra classes to those image widgets for styling, which is what I did; it was the easiest way to create the kind of grid I needed.    I also attempted to just manually create divs with links and style the links with background-image but wasn't able to get the images to display properly in all browsers.  I also tried img:hover but it only worked in Chrome and not Firefox.  I'll paste in a JSFiddle, one sec.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you cannot give content to none pseudo (:before, :after) elements with CSS in FireFox. Your coding would work otherwise. You could do it like this:

```
.advertising a{
width:250px;
height:250px;
background:url('http://lorempizza.com/250/250');
display:block;
}
.advertising a:hover {
background:url('http://lorempixel.com/250/250')
z-index: 1;
opacity: 1;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/juo7abyo/1/)

Comment: Is there a way to make that code responsive?  That was part of the problem I was having with the use of background:url()

Comment: @user3916481 what do you mean responsive? do you mean animated? like fade in the picture on hover?

Comment: No, like it will resize if the browser window is resized.